# php file doesn't redirect

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, authentication

I am trying to learn how to make a basic login system using PHP and MySQL. I am following a tutorial (http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html), but it isn't working.

I tested it out and the inputs from the form on the previous page are working, but it isn't redirecting to the next page. Here's the code. Also, the MySQL connection is working, I'm just hiding the password.

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost", "metacano_joe", "************") or die ("cannot   connect");

    mysql_select_db("metacano_metacanon") or die(mysql_error());

    $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count==1){
        session_register("myusername");
        session_register("mypassword");
        header("location:login_success.php");
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
?>
```

Comment: For starters... `session_register()` that's deprecated. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`

Comment: That's not the only thing that's deprecated ;)

Comment: Not sure if it is important, but did you try using `header("Location: login_success.php");`, meaning keep the capitalization "Location" instead of "location"?

Comment: Agreed, mysql_connect is also deprecated, mysqli_* functions come with a lot more security.

Comment: Please go find an read a tutorial that explains how basic error checking and debugging in PHP can be done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: add this your hosts file `phpeasystep.com 127.0.0.1`

Comment: The tutorial must be old. Time to research the updated functions

Answer (score 4):

*Gotta love not being able to comment*

Assuming your code is correct, there are 2 possibilities why it isn't redirecting.

- $count != 1. Aka username password combination doesn't exit.
- You're outputting something before the header.

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Side notes. Stop using deprecated functions. Please.

Also, do you get any error outputs?

Comment: I think this stands perfectly fine as an answer. +1

Comment: Or the username / password contains a `'`. And I agree with @Phil :-)

Comment: ...it could be a mix of many possible reasons.

Comment: I did specify that I'm assuming his code is correct. Either way, a few prepared statements wouldn't hurt...

Comment: @user2997488 I couldn't agree with you more ;) OP's code contains too many possible errors and we don't know what the PHP version is, which could be the major issue, maybe even form's elements aren't named, could be anything. You stand at being correct. Will +1 - You're well on your way to be able to comment, cheers.

Comment: Live and learn brother, live and learn. God knows I'd be laughing at what I wrote 2 months ago. And I'll probably laugh 2 months from now at what I write today.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am going to learn the updated functions the tutorial wasn't using.

Comment: No problem man. When in doubt always look it up on php.net. Search for similar questions on stackoverflow, google is always there for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost", "metacano_joe", "************") or die ("cannot   connect");

    mysql_select_db("metacano_metacanon") or die(mysql_error());

    $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count>1){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['myusername'] = "myusername";
        $_SESSION['mypassword'] = "mypassword";
        header("location:login_success.php");
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
?>
```

I edit your script, you can use $_SESSION, it's good for starter

Comment: This did help but I think i have more issues in the code to figure out

Comment: What is it @JosephBenedetti

Comment: The code i posted worked but the file it redirected to didn't work. Also it seems that I have a lot of deprecated functions

Comment: make sure your file is in the same folder with the file you use to call this code